# LookupError: App 'accounts' doesn't have a 'user' model --- "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label , model_name))

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am trying to create a custom signup form for which i have extended **django** inbuilt user model.I am also using **django-postman** for user to user messaging.Postman was working quite fine till i was using inbuilt user model,however when i used the custom user model it started showing me this Lookup error(only while creating messages).I have done some research to solve this but failed.

the traceback error

```
 class MadeLookupChannel(LookupChannel):
  File "C:\Users\vishw\Envs\Vishwesh2_env\lib\site-pack
ages\ajax_select\registry.py", line 104, in MadeLookupC
hannel
    model = get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "C:\Users\vishw\Envs\Vishwesh2_env\lib\site-pack
ages\ajax_select\registry.py", line 123, in get_model
    return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)
  File "C:\Users\vishw\Envs\Vishwesh2_env\lib\site-pack
ages\django\apps\registry.py", line 205, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_rea
dy=require_ready)
  File "C:\Users\vishw\Envs\Vishwesh2_env\lib\site-pack
ages\django\apps\config.py", line 172, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'accounts' doesn't have a 'user' model
```

However i have also added this in my settings.py file in order to solve this

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.Profile'
```

then it shows this error

```
 File "C:\Users\vishw\OneDrive\Documents\Projects_2\si
mple_social_clone\simplesocial\postman\apps.py", line 1
3, in ready
    setup()
  File "C:\Users\vishw\OneDrive\Documents\Projects_2\si
mple_social_clone\simplesocial\postman\models.py", line
 57, in setup
    name_user_as = getattr(settings, 'POSTMAN_NAME_USER
_AS', get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD)
AttributeError: type object 'Profile' has no attribute
'USERNAME_FIELD'
```

this is my accounts.models.py here my Profile model extending the built in user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import auth
from django.utils import timezone
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Profile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES=(
     ('M','Male'),
     ('F','Female'),
     ('O','Other')
    )
    BRANCH_CHOICES=(
    ('IT','Information Technology'),
    ('COMP','Computer Science')
    )
    QUAL_CHOICES=(
    ('BE','BE-Bachelor of Engineering'),
    ('Btech','Btech-Bachelor of Technology'),
    ('ME','ME-Master of Engineering'),
    ('Mtech','Mtech-Master of Technology')
    )
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    branch=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=BRANCH_CHOICES)
    mob=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    highest_qual=models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=QUAL_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
```

this is postman.models.py file snap where the error was occuring

```
def setup():
    """
    Deferred actions, that can not be done at import time since Django 1.7.
    Normally called in AppConfig.ready().
    For backwards compatibility, also called on first need.

    """
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    name_user_as = getattr(settings, 'POSTMAN_NAME_USER_AS', get_user_model().USERNAME_FIELD)
    ORDER_BY_FIELDS.update({
        'f': 'sender__' + name_user_as,     # as 'from'
        't': 'recipient__' + name_user_as,  # as 'to'
        's': 'subject',  # as 'subject'
        'd': 'sent_at',  # as 'date'
    })
```

**please help me with this!**

Answer (score 2):

You *don't* have a custom user model. You have a Profile model which links to the built-in user model. There is no need to set AUTH_USER_MODEL; you should remove that setting.

Comment: please help me with this!